# Simple master-detail view iPad application

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ipad, master-detail

I've been working on a simple master-detail view iPad application. In the master view are the names of students where they are grouped according to their section. In the detail view are their basic information and a section just below the basic info, where you can find dates and their signature (as an attendance of some sort to that respective date). So yeah, as you can see, this is some sort of a database.

I can already do the adding and deleting new names, but they are still ungrouped. And when I click a name, it already shows in the detail view. I keep on putting a Dynamic Prototype table at the detail view (for the basic information) but I don't really know how to add the other information to make it display on the detail view. I know it uses serialization but I have no idea on how to implement it.

I'm really new on developing iOS apps so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!